# Sync two git repositories, but with different authors

Tags: git, github, gitlab

We are a software house, and we will work on an existing software product of a client (CompanyA).
They have provided us with access to their existing repository.
It is us exclusively who are going to work on that project.
However, that client hired some senior people from our team in the past, which had significant consequences for us.
Thus, we do not want them to know the names/emails of our people who work on their product, because they will definitely try to hire them.

We plan to **duplicate** the repo internally.
Our people will normally commit to the internal repo with their names/emails.
And we plan to sync regularly with CompanyA's repository.

We want to replace the author for all of our commits on CompanyA's repository with a more generic "Development Team" and Developers@ourCompany.com.

**This is what we thought:**

1. Initially push/duplicate CompanyA's existing repository on our internal Github.
2. Create master_OurCompany, which will be based on their current master branch. Our developers will use this as their master repo.
3. Every hour, we plan to create (and then destroy) a branch based on master_OurCompany named master_OurCompany_rebased.
4. On master_OurCompany_rebased, we plan to use the `git filter-branch --commit-filter` command to replace the authors in that branch with the information we want.
5. And then to merge master_OurCompany_rebased with CompanyA's master branch.

However, we have found out that the `git filter-branch --commit-filter` is a dangerous one to use, and has [a plethora of pitfalls](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). We do not want anything unfortunate to happen, from which we cannot recover.

What could be some safer ways to achieve our requirements above?

Comment: I think a solution built around two internal repositories, `git format-patch`, and `git am` might be a better choice, but this seems like you're trying to solve a social problem with technical tools, and I suspect that any programmatic solution isn't really solving the right thing.

Comment: If they don't respect your terms, then just don't work with them.

Answer (score 0):

> However, we have found out that the git filter-branch --commit-filter is a dangerous one to use, and has a plethora of pitfalls.

Well, hard cheese, as they say. `filter-branch` or the newer `filter-repo` is *exactly* what you're going to have to use. You are trying to rewrite history *en masse*, which is always scary. Make a backup and take the plunge.